# how to change the value of a specific key in short words in php

Tags: php, arrays

Array of title to be replaced with  words temporary

```
    Array ( 
           [title] => LED Flash Macro Ring Light (48 X LED) with 6 Adapter Rings for For Canon/Sony/Nikon/Sigma Lenses 
           [manufacturer] => Neewer Electronics Accessories 
           [currency] => CAD 
           [price] => 35.99 
     )
```

convert the title values to have less words temporary to compare with another key

```
 Array ( 
       [title] => LED Flash Macro Ring 
       [manufacturer] => Neewer Electronics Accessories 
       [currency] => CAD 
       [price] => 35.99 
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure if this would suffice but you could try the following.

```
$title=$arr['title'];
$length=30;
$smalltitle=rtrim( preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/', '', substr( $title, 0, $length ) ) );
echo $smalltitle;

$arr['title']=$smalltitle;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my example:

```
<?php
function shorter($title) {
    $maxWords = 4;
    $count = 0;
    $len = strlen($title);
    $result = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        if ($title[$i] == ' ') {
            $count++;
        }

        if ($count == $maxWords) {
            break;
        }
        $result .= $title[$i];
    }
    return $result;
}


$arr = array ( 
  'title' => 'LED Flash Macro Ring Light (48 X LED) with 6 Adapter Rings for For Canon/Sony/Nikon/Sigma Lenses',
  'manufacturer' => 'Neewer Electronics Accessories',
  'currency' => 'CAD',
  'price' => 35.99 
);

$arr['title'] = shorter($arr['title']);
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can re-assign the value of "title" index. below is code.It will work for you.

```
   $arr = array(
            'title'=>'LED Flash Macro Ring Light (48 X LED) with 6 Adapter Rings for For Canon/Sony/Nikon/Sigma Lenses',
            'manufacturer'=>' Neewer Electronics Accessories',
            'currency'=>'CAD!'
    );

    $str['title'] = 'LED Flash Macro Ring!';
    foreach($arr as $val){
       echo $val . '<br />';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
```

$arry = array("title"=>"LED Flash Macro Ring Light (48 X LED) with 6 Adapter Rings for For Canon/Sony/Nikon/Sigma Lenses", "manufacturer" => "Neewer Electronics Accessories","currency"=>"CAD","price"=>"35.99");

```
 foreach($arry as $key =>$row) 
 {
    if($key == "title")
    {
        $explode = explode("Light",$row);
        $arry[$key] = $explode[0];
    }
 }
 print_r($arry);
```

?>

Comment: **ARRAYS**

Array ( [productname] => Sony Cyber-shot DSC-W310 [manufacturer] => Sony [model] => DSC-W310 [family] => Cyber-shot [announced-date] => 2010-01-06T19:00:00.000-05:00 ) Array ( [productname] => Samsung TL240 [manufacturer] => Samsung [model] => TL240 [announced-date] => 2010-01-05T19:00:00.000-05:00 ) Array ( [productname] => Nikon-s6100 [manufacturer] => Nikon [model] => S6100 [family] => Coolpix [announced-date] => 2011-02-08T19:00:00.000-05:00 ) 
 }

Comment: How to show individual productname key values in a variable Anyone can tell me?